# Meaning of String.Format in C# in the following context?

Tags: c#, xpath, string.format, xpathnodeiterator

I was just going through certain code...I wanted to know what the following code means

```
string format = "//User[UserName=\"{0}\" and EncryptPassword=\"{1}\"]";
string xpath = String.Format( format, userName, password );
```

xpath is later used to create xPathNodeIterator object. I dont quite understand how String.Format is used and which node will the XPathNodeIterator will be iterating through if I  iterate?

Comment: Have you tested it? What don't you understand?

Comment: There are some other errors in the program and I am trying to understand these two statements before I get to the other errors.

Comment: What I dont understand is what does String.Format do? And how can whatever format given there be used to create a XpathNodeIterator object

Comment: Use the debugger and set a breakpoint at the second line. Then you can see what `String.Format( format, userName, password );` returns. Always consult [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx) first before you ask a question on stackoverflow regarding the functionality of a method.

Comment: I didn't quite understand this link since it was not illustrated with an example. The other answers gives me a clear idea.

Comment: I have posted the wrong link, have a look at the remarks section of the `String.Format` overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Format(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the details of [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx). It

> Replaces each format item in a specified string with the text equivalent of a corresponding object's value.

it means that *xpath* will contain *format*  string where *{0}* in the *format* string will be replaced with value of *username* and *{1}* will be replaced with value of *password*

Assuming that

```
string userName = "Ehsan";
string password = "Password";
string format = "//User[UserName=\"{0}\" and EncryptPassword=\"{1}\"]";
string xpath = String.Format(format, userName, password);
```

Xpath will be equivalent to

```
//User[UserName="Ehsan" and EncryptPassword="Password"]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is roughly equivalent to the code

```
string xpath = "//User[UserName=\"" + userName.ToString() + "\" and EncryptPassword=\"" + password.ToString() + "\"]";
```

`String.Format` just lets you replace placeholders in test strings easily and optionally add additional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It just means *"use `userName` and `password` for `{0}` and `{1}` respectively, in the string `"//User[UserName=\"{0}\" and EncryptPassword=\"{1}\"]";`*

That will give you the resulting string:

```
"//User[UserName=\"John\" and EncryptPassword=\"correctHorseBatteryStaple\"]"
```

(assuming the value of userName was `John`, and... well, [you can guess the password](http://xkcd.com/936/)).

Comment: So if this string is taken to make an object of the xpathNodeIterator, the object iterates through username and password both? That is, each iterator object can access both these values?

Comment: Well the answer to your OP is basically that **it provides you a string that can be used as an XPath**. Nothing more. As for the lookup itself, I'm not that familiar with XPath - but if I'm not mistaken, it just selects a node of type `User` which has the attributes `UserName` and `EncryptPassword` with those two values.

Answer (score 0):

Assume:

```
userName = "Peter"
password = "abc123"
```

Your xpath will be:

```
String.Format(format, userName, password)
String.Format("//User[UserName=\"{0}\" and EncryptPassword=\"{1}\"]", "Peter", "abc123")
```

As the {0} is replaced by userName, "Peter", and {1} is replaced by passowrd, "abc123", your xpath becomes:

```
//User[UserName="Peter" and EncryptedPassword="abc123"]
```

The thing to remember is that all those {0}, {1}, etc will be replaced by strings that follow.